# How to delete a field programmatically

Tags: 8, users

I've got a service managing the install/uninstall of my module.

Install create a field attached to the user but I am not able to delete it during the uninstall process...

**stacko.services.yml**

```
services:
  stacko.module_installer:
    class: Drupal\stacko\ModuleInstaller
    arguments:
      - '@entity_type.manager'
    tags:
      - { name: service_collector, tag: 'module_install.uninstall_validator', call: addUninstallValidator }
```

**stacko.install**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_install().
 */
function stacko_install() {
  $module_installer = Drupal::service('stacko.module_installer');
  $module_installer->install([]);
}

/**
 * Implements hook_uninstall().
 */
function stacko_uninstall() {
  $module_installer = Drupal::service('stacko.module_installer');
  $module_installer->uninstall([]);
}
```

**src/ModuleInstaller.php**

```
namespace Drupal\stacko;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleInstallerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleUninstallValidatorInterface;
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig;

/**
 * Module installer.
 */
class ModuleInstaller implements ModuleInstallerInterface {

  /**
   * Field storage config manager.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\field\FieldStorageConfigStorage
   */
  protected $fieldStorageConfigManager;

  /**
   * Field config manager.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\field\FieldConfigInterface
   */
  protected $fieldConfigManager;

  /**
   * Constructor.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager
   *   The entityt type manager.
   */
  public function __construct(EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager) {
    $this->fieldStorageConfigManager = $entity_type_manager->getStorage('field_storage_config');
    $this->fieldConfigManager = $entity_type_manager->getStorage('field_config');
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function install(array $module_list, $enable_dependencies = TRUE) {
    $this->createFields();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function uninstall(array $module_list, $uninstall_dependents = TRUE) {
    $this->deleteFields();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function addUninstallValidator(ModuleUninstallValidatorInterface $uninstall_validator) {
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validateUninstall(array $module_list) {
  }

  /**
   * Create all fields.
   */
  protected function createFields() {
    $this->createStackoField();
  }

  /**
   * Create Stacko field.
   */
  protected function createStackoField() {
    $this->createStackoFieldStorage();
    $this->createStackoFieldInstance();
  }

  /**
   * Delete all fields.
   */
  protected function deleteFields() {
    $this->deleteStackoField();
  }

  /**
   * Create Stacko field storage.
   */
  protected function createStackoFieldStorage() {
    try {
      $this->fieldStorageConfigManager->create([
        'field_name' => 'field_stacko',
        'entity_type' => 'user',
        'type' => 'text',
        'cardinality' => 1,
        'locked' => FALSE,
        'indexes' => [],
        'settings' => [
          'max_length' => 14,
          'is_ascii' => false,
          'case_sensitive' => false,
        ],
      ])->save();
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
      if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') {
        drush_print_r('Either the field_stacko storage already exists or an error occured and it has not been created.');
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Create Stacko field instance.
   */
  protected function createStackoFieldInstance() {
    try {
      $this->fieldConfigManager->create([
        'field_name' => 'field_stacko',
        'entity_type' => 'user',
        'bundle' => 'user',
        'label' => 'The stacko',
        'required' => FALSE,
        'settings' => [],
      ])->save();
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
      if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') {
        drush_print_r('Either the field_stacko instance already exists or an error occured and it has not been created.');
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Delete Stacko field storage.
   */
  protected function deleteStackoField() {
    // Leads to Error: Call to undefined method Drupal\field\FieldStorageConfigStorage::loadByName()
    /* if ($this->fieldStorageConfigManager->loadByName('user', 'field_stacko')) {
      $field_storage->delete();
    } */
    // Doesn't load the field storage | doesn't delete the field.
    /* if ($field_storage = $this->fieldStorageConfigManager->loadByProperties([
      'entity_type' => 'user',
      'field_name' => 'field_stacko',
    ])) {
      kint('test 1');
      $field_storage->delete();
    }
    kint('test 2'); */
    // Doesn't load the field storage | doesn't delete the field.
    if ($field_storage = FieldStorageConfig::loadByName('user', 'field_stacko')) {
      kint('test 1');
      $field_storage->delete();
    }
    kint('test 2');
  }

}
```

While running `deleteStackoField()` I only have the 'test 2' message. As it's unable to load the field storage, the field is not deleted.

So I am wondering how can I properly delete my field programmatically ?

Comment: Where did you see this example implementing your own ModuleInstaller? It's unclear what you are trying to achieve other than run code inside of both hooks. Implementing such a service does only makes sense for a more general task applying to all extensions and then you would rather register to the existing service collector. Apart from this user fields are installed and uninstalled automatically when placed in the config folder of a module. See for example the two YAML files for the user_picture field placed in the standard profile: /core/profiles/standard/config/install

Comment: See also https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/297495/47547

Comment: So I manually deleted my field, removed my service and .install file, flushed the cache, added the 2 yml files to the module config/install folder. When I install the module, the field is created but it is not deleted at all when I uninstall the module even if I flush the cache or run the cron

Comment: Ok with the dependency enforced it works. Thanks @4k4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I followed [@4k4](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/47547/4k4) advices.

Best way to create and delete a field during install/uninstall process is to add the field storage and config yml files to the config/install folder of the module and enforce a dependency to the module.

**config/install/field.field.user.user.field_stacko.yml**

```
langcode: fr
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - field.storage.user.field_stacko
  module:
    - text
    - user
  enforced:
    module:
      - stacko
id: user.user.field_stacko
field_name: field_stacko
entity_type: user
bundle: user
label: 'The stacko'
description: ''
required: false
translatable: true
default_value: {  }
default_value_callback: ''
settings: {  }
field_type: text
```

**config/install/field.storage.user.field_stacko.yml**

```
langcode: fr
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - text
    - user
  enforced:
    module:
      - stacko
id: user.field_stacko
field_name: field_stacko
entity_type: user
type: text
settings:
  max_length: 14
module: text
locked: false
cardinality: 1
translatable: true
indexes: {  }
persist_with_no_fields: false
custom_storage: false
```