# Remove config when uninstalling custom module

Tags: 8, configuration

I have made a custom module with a config/install folder containing many yml files from a drush configuration export.
When activating the module , it does install the configuration.
How can i delete all this config when i uninstall the module ?

Comment: You can implement hook_uninstall to delete configuration entities.

Comment: Or add a dependency on the custom module to the config files, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/297487/how-to-properly-manage-field-types-for-a-content-type-created-by-a-module

Comment: @leymannx the answer yes. I would say the question is not a duplicate though even if the answer is the same

Comment: @4k4 I have added the dependency and it does work as long as no other config refer to the module config (in my case another paragrah referring to the one in the module ) and in that case it crashes when uninstalling with Call to a member function getEnabledBehaviorPlugins() on null in Drupal\paragraphs\ParagraphViewBuilder->buildMultiple() (line 37 of modules/contrib/paragraphs/src/ParagraphViewBuilder.php). any idea ?

Comment: In my case my module create a new paragraph. if using this paragraph in one content, and not suppressing in that content the ref to the paragraph before uninstalling the module , it generates that error above