# How to uninstall a custom module which introduces a field type and creates a field of that type on install?

Tags: 8

Ading a new field to a content type by adding `field.storage.node.myfield.yml` & `field.field.node.article.myfield.yml` configs to `config/install` directory of my `custom_module` module.

This field is of type `customfieldtype` which is defined in the `custom_module` module itself.

This adds a new field `myfield` of type `customfieldtype` to the `article` content type.

Now if I try to uninstall this module via the UI, it doesn't allow the module to uninstall because of this dependency:
`The MyField field type is used in the following field: node.myfield`

Question: Do we require to move the plugin implementation of `customfieldtype` to be in a separate module? Can we not achieve the uninstall on this custom module?

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/297487/how-to-properly-manage-field-types-for-a-content-type-created-by-a-module

Comment: Thanks @4k4 for the reply. This is suggesting to add enforced module dependency on the field storage configuration. which is fine when I want to remove the field when module gets uninstalled. But the problem is the custom module itself is the provider of that field type and hence the uninstall validation doesn't allow the provider module to be uninstalled without removing the storage first.

Comment: have you deleted the content related tot the custom module, then deleted the custom module?

Comment: yup @Joehoe, removed the content before uninstall.